# Typescript alias for builtin type

Tags: typescript

How can i make alias for built in type such as from [utility-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), i have definition which have the same name as builtin types, and happen to use type with the same name from builtin types, example :

```
interface Record { // <-- my definition

   toObject() : Record<string, object> // <-- built in definition
}
```

does not work

```
type TsRecord<K,V> = Record<K, V>
```

if there is an import method, i cant find the reference

```
import {Record as TsRecord} from ?
```

Comment: Types are not like variables; you cannot "reassign" them. Use a different name for your type.

Comment: @kaya3 i assume that can be reassign, because "other" can be reassign, like : import Reassign, {Type as ReassignType} from "path"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using TypeScript 3.4 or above, you can use the [`globalThis` namespace](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis) to access global types whose names have been shadowed by local declarations:

```
interface Record { // <-- my definition
  toObject(): globalThis.Record<string, object> // <-- built in definition
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7xgCwJaoJKoCCAshACYCuANsHALxwAMA3AFCvbIzBQBmAhgloAlYEihk4AbzgB6WXAA8AWmVwAtgE84ZYL07YY2FKzhwYEAPIAjAFZiYACgCUALjgBzKhGv8qAFRxUADpRcTJFdChODwAaOB97BBgAPjkFFTVrCmwqeE4dPQMjEwBfIA)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. 

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have to use the name Record for your own definition but you could reuse the source for the record utility type for the custom TsRecord type:

```
type TsRecord<K extends keyof any, T> = {
  [P in K]: T;
};

interface Record {
  // <-- my definition
  toObject(): TsRecord<string, object>; 
}
```

Or rename your own definition:

```
interface TsRecord {
  // <-- my definition
  toObject(): Record<string, object>; 
}
```

Comment: i can't tell the real reason, let say on large structure name collision is quite common, that is why most language give type alias feature